# Sync between Linux process running at different speeds

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ipc, message-queue, i2c

I have two processes written in C, one process let's say A fetches data from an I2C device at 1ms rate and another process let's say B takes this data and feeds to a python script (via a system call) which writes to a socket. I am using message queues to share data between the processes.

The problem I am facing is that sometimes B takes a long time to feed data to the socket. since A queries data at 1ms rate, the queue becomes full and thus query rate also reduces i.e., when queue is full, B must-read data from queue, only then A can pump the data to queue and then read new data from the device and then wait for space in queue.

I have a constraint that I should query the data from the `I2c` device at `1ms`.

How should I handle that A can keep collecting data and also handle the slow execution of B?

Comment: Can you have multiple copies of B running at the same time?

Comment: Does B blocks while feeding the data to the Python script? Make sure you do it in asynchronously. If not possible for some reason, create two seperate thread in B. One should communicate with A and other should feed the data to Python script.

Comment: You have to use RTOS for that with a proper driver.